# AjaxToolkit: Can't drag and drop a ajax toolkit control to a webform

Tags: asp.net

I set a reference to AjaxControlToolkit.dll and this added all of the toolkit's controls to my toolbar. I then tried to drag and drop one of the controls to my webform and nothing happened-no error message, no control added to the form. Double clicking the control also did nothing.

The web site compiles with no errors, I also tried to bounce VS2008. I am running Developers Edition on Windows Server 2008.

I was able to add a Script Manager control

This worked w/o issue on my other computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajaxtoolkit controls in VS2008 are extenders of other controls. Add the parent control first.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you drop the tools into the source tab of your ASP page. As many of these controls has no graphical representation.